# Resolving nunjucks includes using relative paths?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, nunjucks

Is there a way to get the `include` to understand relative paths with respect to the file that the `include` statement is in?

### Background

I have the following two files:

```
├── privacy
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── index.md.html
```

Inside of `index.html` I have the following include:

```
{% block content %} 
{% include "./privacy/index.md.html" %}
{% endblock %} </body>
```

And it works however this does not:

```
{% block content %} 
{% include "./index.md.html" %}
{% endblock %} </body>
```

From what I can tell this is because the `privacy` folder is located in `src/test/html/privacy`.  I have configured nunjucks to resolve files from this directory:

nunjucks.configure(['src/test/html']);

Comment: Try looking here - it seems like a much requested feature that someone found a way to implement- though there is still some debate as to what security risks are imposed by allowing nunjucks to reach "out of the box" to relative paths. Have a look-- https://github.com/mozilla/nunjucks/pull/349

Comment: Interesting - I see that's from 2015, so one would think it would be in there by now - I also asked the question on the repository - but no feedback so far - https://github.com/mozilla/nunjucks/issues/1214

Comment: I thought about that too. I only fear that since it's from 2015, it might have been added, and then removed again for security reasons. Best of luck either way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nunjucks does not allow relative paths.  All paths are relative to the configured base directories.

### Reference

[Using relative paths inside an include?](https://github.com/mozilla/nunjucks/issues/1214)